# How to read a local conf file using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dropbox-api, configuration-files

I have a dropbox.conf on my desktop. Want to read this file using Jupyter Notebook, but all of my attempts of creating the directory failed.

```
#fn = "/Desktop/dropbox.conf"
#fn = 'C:\Desktop\dropbox.conf'
#fn = 'C:/Users/dropbox.conf'
```

After creating the directory, the following code of opening the file is this:

```
with open(fn) as fh:
    credentials = yaml.load(fh)
```

It returns the following error (if I'm using the second directory):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Desktop\\dropbox.conf'
```

Update: When I tried the followings:

```
#fn = open("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\dropbox.conf")
#fn = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\dropbox.conf"
```

The error shows like this:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: what is failing? if you post the error you're receiving and stacktrace, we can help you more

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Desktop\\dropbox.conf'

Comment: you should double check that the filepath of your file is correct. windows typically doesn't have a `Desktop` directory in the C drive. It's typically `C:\Users\khuynh\Desktop\dropbox.conf` or similar.

Comment: I'm using a Macbook, and when I used C:\Users\myname\Desktop\dropbox.conf, it returns this error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Please double check your file path. Mac doesn't use the letter drives in filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from pathlib import Path

conf = Path("C:\Desktop\dropbox.conf")

conf.read_text()
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the error is still -- No such file or directory: 'C:\\Desktop\\dropbox.conf'